# Why does floor() return value less by 1?

Tags: php, floor

I'm doing some calculation in PHP using floor() method and find out this.

**Code:**

```
<?php
   echo(floor(69950.40-10670.40) . "<br>");
   echo(69950.40-10670.40);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
59279
59280
```

***Note:*** I want it to be **59280** even after floor().

I don't know why it's happening.
Any ideas friends?

Comment: Use `ceil` not `floor`.

Comment: It has [a simple explanation](https://3v4l.org/iHQM2).

Comment: @AksenP your link does not provide any information other than some example.

Comment: @Nicolas, great)

Comment: This is a problem due to the precision of floating point numbers in php. Try `echo printf('%.20f', 69950.40-10670.40);`, you will get `59279.9999999999927240423926`, which is floored to 59279.

Comment: @laucho "the precision of floating point numbers in php" --- IEEE754 works the same way in every other language.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that too @laucho but how do I solve this. I have to use floor() as a part of the calculation. Any idea how?

Comment: One trick used in a couple of languages is to OR 0 with the result, such as `$val = (69950.40-10670.40) | 0;` - not sure if this works in PHP as well but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I tried this and overcame the error.

**Code:**

```
$number = 69950.40-10670.40;
$number = sprintf("%.2f",$number);
echo(floor($number) . "<br>");
```

**Output:**

```
59280
```

I don't know if it's the right way, but it's what I need.

Answer (score -3):

use `round()` instead of `floor()`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jaya Rathinam but it's just a part of a calculation i'm performing and i really have to use floor();